# Trying to access the reputation audit page while logged out shows an incorrect error message of not having the privilege to answer protected questions

Tags: bug, error-message, reputation-audit, anonymous-visitors

One day, I was trying to access my reputation audit page at `/reputation`, and got an error message saying I don't have the privilege to access the page:

> ### This page requires more privileges
>
> The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege “[Answer protected questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).”
>
> You receive additional privileges on [site name] by earning more [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) through participation on the site. When you have earned at least 10 reputation, you will receive the “Answer protected questions” privilege and will be allowed to view this page.
>
> Visit the [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to learn more about the privileges you can earn.

I was wondering why all of a sudden it was saying I didn't have the privilege to answer protected questions. It has absolutely nothing to do with the page I was trying to access.

Eventually, I figured out that my session had timed out and I was logged out of the site. I logged back in and was able to access the page just fine.

Can trying to access the page while logged out no longer show an error message about answering protected questions, and instead show a more proper error message that one needs to log in?

Also, it seems to me that this error occurs because as an anti-DDoS provision, accessing the `/reputation` page is now blocked for users who don't have the privilege to remove new user restrictions (the actual privilege linked to in the error message). If that's so, can the error message please indicate this as the privilege to remove new user restrictions rather than the privilege to answer protected questions?

Comment: Yeah, anti-DDoS measures make SE do really weird things sometimes, and due to the "security risk" they can't even tell. So doubt they'll make any changes or admit that's the case.

Comment: The page is actually not restricted by reputation at all. We only send back the privilege required page when a user is not logged in, for some reason. It seems to have gotten changed from throwing a 404 to displaying the privilege message back in 2012 as part of a larger SEO project, though I'm sure the information on why this specific change was included is lost now. I'd venture a guess that throwing a 404 there was causing problems with it being linked a bunch on Meta? _shrugs_